# Why SOAP request without SOAPAction and even operation name in envelope still works?

Tags: soap

I've encountered a strange thing:
I send the SOAP request to the SOAP service provider, the SOAP request envelop has no SOAPAction header and no operation name in the body. But the response still be OK.
This is my WSDL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="urn:com.tung.switchyard:soap-hello:1.0" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" name="IHello" targetNamespace="urn:com.tung.switchyard:soap-hello:1.0">
  <wsdl:types>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="urn:com.tung.switchyard:soap-hello:1.0" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" targetNamespace="urn:com.tung.switchyard:soap-hello:1.0" version="1.0">
<xs:element name="greetingResponse" type="tns:greetingResponse"/>
<xs:element name="person" type="tns:person"/>
<xs:complexType name="person">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="sex" type="xs:boolean"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
<xs:complexType name="greetingResponse">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="response" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="NewOperation">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>

                        <xs:element name="in" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="NewOperationResponse">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>

                        <xs:element name="out" type="xs:string"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="hello">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:person" name="arg0">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="NewOperationRequest">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:person" name="argo">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="helloResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:greetingResponse" name="return">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="NewOperationResponse">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:greetingResponse" name="return">
    </wsdl:part>
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="IHelloPortType">
    <wsdl:operation name="hello">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:hello" name="hello">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:helloResponse" name="helloResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="NewOperation">
      <wsdl:input message="tns:NewOperationRequest">
    </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output message="tns:NewOperationResponse">
    </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="IHelloSoapBinding" type="tns:IHelloPortType">
    <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
    <wsdl:operation name="hello">
      <soap:operation soapAction="hello" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="hello">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="helloResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="NewOperation">
      <soap:operation soapAction="NewOperation" style="document"/>
      <wsdl:input name="NewOperationRequest">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="NewOperationResponse">
        <soap:body use="literal"/>
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="IHello">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:IHelloSoapBinding" name="IHelloPort">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/soap-hello/IHello"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

The request envelop

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:com.tung.switchyard:soap-hello:1.0">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:person>
         <name>John</name><sex>true</sex>
      </urn:person>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>
   <soap:Body>
      <greetingResponse xmlns="urn:com.tung.switchyard:soap-hello:1.0">
         <response>Hello John</response>
      </greetingResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Comment: Can you share response also?

Comment: Hi Ashraf, please check the response I added

Comment: You are using SOAP UI? or generated a client?

Comment: No, I use java code to send the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your WSDL file you have mentioned the soap action attribute for both of services and both of the services have same request and response elements. SOAP Action attribute is send in Http Post Header. When you send it without SOAP Action it will fail. I have executed a test and below are the logs.

**Without SOAP Action**

```
POST /DemoWS/services/IHello HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: application/soap+xml, application/dime, multipart/related, text/*
User-Agent: Axis/1.4
Host: localhost:8080
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
SOAPAction: ""
Content-Length: 375

Request Envelope

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><person xmlns="urn:com.tung.switchyard:soap-hello:1.0"><name xmlns="">Test</name><sex xmlns="">true</sex></person></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>

Error Response Envelope

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Body><axis2ns2:Fault xmlns:axis2ns2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><faultcode>axis2ns2:Client</faultcode><faultstring>The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is http://localhost:8080/DemoWS/services/IHello and the WSA Action = . If this EPR was previously reachable, please contact the server administrator.</faultstring><detail/></axis2ns2:Fault></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```

**With SOAP Action** - it works fine

```
POST /DemoWS/services/IHello HTTP/1.0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: application/soap+xml, application/dime, multipart/related, text/*
User-Agent: Axis/1.4
Host: localhost:8080
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
SOAPAction: "NewOperation"
Content-Length: 375

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><soapenv:Body><person xmlns="urn:com.tung.switchyard:soap-hello:1.0"><name xmlns="">Test</name><sex xmlns="">true</sex></person></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```